# Convert NSLocalizedString to NSAttributedString uppercase the text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsattributedstring, nslocalizedstring

Steps to reproduce:

```
let testString  = NSLocalizedString("test", comment: "string for test")
let testStringAttributed = NSAttributedString(string: testString)

print(testStringAttributed)
```

expected result : test

actual result : TEST

I am using 7.3.1, swift 2.2

You can see I didn't even set attributes, even with attributed (with a font style regular) the result is the same.
This is an unexpected behaviour and I have to be able to localize my attributed strings in my app (basically a text I set in a label with links).
Any known workaround?

P.S.: Setting the string to lowercase removes the uppercase BUT makes me lose any attributes I set. Not a viable option here.

Comment: It can be caused by missing translation for this key.

Comment: You can change it by 
Where sillyString -> input string

print(sillyString.uppercaseString)
print(sillyString.lowercaseString)

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to a missing translation like Timur Bernikowich suggested.

NSLocalizedString is supposed to return the key in the event of a missing translation but it appears in the case of a conversion to NSAttributedString the string gets uppercase.

Putting the proper translation in Localizable.string and calling the key fixed the problem